# QUERY FAILED.. error in your SQL syntax;.. check MariaDB for the right syntax to use near ''customer_pass' = '899b573719facc368f32770ea0b68e32'

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a sign up form, it was working fine until I tried to add md5 to the password field set, I'm not sure why the Query failed. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function sign_up(){

    if(isset($_POST['register'])){

        $c_email            = escape_string($_POST['c_email']);
        $c_name_first       = escape_string($_POST['c_name_first']);
        $c_name_last        = escape_string($_POST['c_name_last']);
        $c_pass             = escape_string($_POST['c_pass']);
        $c_image            = escape_string($_FILES['c_image']['name']);
        $c_image_tmp        = escape_string($_FILES['c_image']['tmp_name']);
        $c_address          = escape_string($_POST['c_address']);
        $c_address_details  = escape_string($_POST['c_address_details']);
        $c_city             = escape_string($_POST['c_city']);
        $c_state            = escape_string($_POST['c_state']);
        $c_zip              = escape_string($_POST['c_zip']);
        $c_contact          = escape_string($_POST['c_phone']);


        move_uploaded_file($c_image_tmp, "customer/customer_images/$c_image");

        $query = query("SELECT customer_id FROM customers WHERE customer_email = '{$c_email}'");
        confirm($query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

            set_message("This email or username is taken");

        }else {

            $insert_c = query("INSERT INTO customers (customer_firstname,customer_lastname,customer_address,c_addr_details,customer_email,customer_pass,customer_state,customer_city,customer_zip,customer_phone,customer_image) VALUES ('$c_name_first','$c_name_last','$c_address','$c_address_details','$c_email','$c_pass','$c_state','$c_city','$c_zip','$c_contact','$c_image')");
            confirm($insert_c);

        }
        $query  = "UPDATE user SET 'customer_pass' = '".md5(md5(last_id()).$c_pass)."' WHERE 'customer_id' = '".last_id()."'";
        $send_update_query = query($query);
        confirm($send_update_query);

        set_message_success("Sign up successful!");


    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not roll your own password hashing scheme. PHP provides [``password_hash()``](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [``password_verify()``](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them. And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet). If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query  = 'UPDATE user SET customer_pass = '.md5(md5(last_id()).$c_pass).' WHERE customer_id = '.last_id();
```

Check you string when you use " or '